# Exporting Pictures from Illustrator into SpriteKit

Tags: swift, sprite-kit, adobe-illustrator

I am very new to creating graphics for sprite kit.

I have drawn some vectoring graphics (simple arrows) in illustrator. They look smooth and nice. However, when I export them as a PNG24 file, and load them into Xcode and run my game, the edges of the arrows are not smooth....?

Is this a sprite kit rendering problem? If not, how can I export pictures from illustrator and have them look the best in sprite kit?

note: My game does scroll...maybe this will effect the graphics..?

Any guidance! Thanks :)

Comment: Screenshots and the size of the images are required to see and understand the nature of the problem.

Comment: The image size from illustrator is 2208 x 1242.

Comment: Screenshots, and how you're importing the artwork, please. I can't "see" anything.

Comment: I wonder why people often  pay attention only to the last part of a sentence :) Anyways, for me, this sounds like exporting problem (export from vector to png resulted in bad quality png due to image editor settings). Also, maybe not a solution for your problem, but certainly a good read : https://developer.apple.com/reference/spritekit/sktexture/1519659-filteringmode

Comment: Thanks for your help guys. I think it is an exporting problem. I don't know how to upload an image thats why i didn't. I managed to change the design of my art and it looks better. 

Cheers :D